# Trying to set this html iframe at a certain place on my page?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to set this html i-frame at a certain place on my page in the body but I can't figure out what code to use or how?

```
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 333px; height: 156px; position src="h: relative;" id="i_div"><iframe name="i_frame"http://url.com/click.php?aff=2057&amp;camp=2056&amp;crt=6077&amp" style="border: 0pt none ; left: -585px; top: -273px; positionabsolute; width: 1024px; height: 576px;" scrolling="no"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: That html is not valid, you have a few errors there...

Comment: A "certain place on the page" is not specific whatsoever. This question lacks all the details required to create any meaningful answer. Do you really have those syntax errors on the page? Where is it appearing versus where you want it to appear?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a drag-and-drop-cut-and-paste mistake. Cleaned up some errors you had in that code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 333px; height: 156px; position: relative;" id="i_div">
  <iframe name="i_frame" 
    src="http://url.com/click.php?aff=2057&amp;camp=2056&amp;crt=6077&amp"
    style="border: 0pt none; left: -585px; top: -273px; position: absolute; width: 1024px; height: 576px;" 
    scrolling="no">
  </iframe>
</div>
```